# get the data from soundcloud and reverbnation for a windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to create a windows 8 app for a particular band who have stored their songs on 
[Reverbation](http://www.reverbnation.com/) and [soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com). My problem is that i dont know how to get those contents from these sites...I tried creating an rss feed using feedburner but that failed. Is there any way where i can get the feed or the data for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundCloud has a well [documented API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs). You can check yourself if the functionality you require is available.

ReverbNation on the other hand [doesn't seem to have a public API available](http://support.reverbnation.com/reverbnation/topics/reverbnation_web_service_api_for_developers) at the moment. There's only an API link in the page footer which opens a dialog for subscribing to any news regarding that via email.